# Angular Detect 401 Unauthorized Access using JWT

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-jwt

I followed a couple of articles to implement JWT authentication on Angular and seems everything is working except detecting 401 unauthorized.

I want to redirect the user to login page but I cannot detect the 401 error.

I have this class:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('HTPP REQUEST');
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.collectFailedRequest(request);
          console.log('Login boy');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But not sure where to use it. I have `auth.service.ts` which contains `login()` and `getToken()` methods and `jwt.interceptor.ts` which contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
providers: [PagerService, AuthService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }, {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: JwtInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

I have to add multiple interceptors in the `module.app.ts`. Don't forget to add `@Injectable()` before `export class...` in the interceptor.